# Mapbox get route issue: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method

Tags: java, android, mapbox

I am following the tutorial for creating a MapBox navigation application. When I get to the point to get a Route, I copy the entire code section, and I check the currentRoute class to see if I indeed get a route, and it returns a direction and other calls to the DirectionsRoute class so I assume I have a route ready to be added. Everything seems to be fine, until I try to add the currentRoute to NavigationMapRoute. Then I get an error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/mapbox/services/commons/geojson/FeatureCollection;Lcom/mapbox/mapboxsdk/style/sources/GeoJsonOptions;)V in class Lcom/mapbox/mapboxsdk/style/sources/GeoJsonSource; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.sources.GeoJsonSource' appears in /data/app/MyApp-IHmaY_75jKlOywZrW4r3Ow==/base.apk)`

I'm confused because I wasn't expecting to fail a call in the tutorial section when I have everything set up. What am I missing here? (Code taken from https://www.mapbox.com/help/android-navigation-sdk/#calculate-and-draw-route)
                                                                      `

```
private void getRoute(com.mapbox.geojson.Point origin, com.mapbox.geojson.Point destination) {
    NavigationRoute.builder()
            .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken())
            .origin(origin)
            .destination(destination)
            .build()
            .getRoute(new Callback<DirectionsResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Response<DirectionsResponse> response) {
                    // You can get the generic HTTP info about the response
                    Log.d(TAG, "Response code: " + response.code());
                    if (response.body() == null) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "No routes found, make sure you set the right user and access token.");
                        return;
                    } else if (response.body().routes().size() < 1) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "No routes found");
                        return;
                    }

                    currentRoute = response.body().routes().get(0);


                    // Draw the route on the map
                    if (navigationMapRoute != null) {
                        navigationMapRoute.removeRoute();
                    } else {

                        navigationMapRoute = new NavigationMapRoute(null, mapView, mapboxMap, R.style.NavigationMapRoute);

                    }

                    navigationMapRoute.addRoute(currentRoute);

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Throwable throwable) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + throwable.getMessage());
                }
            });
}
```

This code is in my onCreate()

```
destinationPosition = com.mapbox.geojson.Point.fromLngLat(-122.269532,37.879842);
originPosition = com.mapbox.geojson.Point.fromLngLat(-122.258875, 37.865593);

getRoute(originPosition, destinationPosition);
```

Build.Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "MyApp"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'

    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.5.1'

    implementation "com.mapzen.android:lost:3.0.2"

    implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.0.1@aar') {
        transitive=true
    }
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.12.0'
    implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.12.0') {
        transitive = true
    }

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

}
```

Full error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/mapbox/services/commons/geojson/FeatureCollection;Lcom/mapbox/mapboxsdk/style/sources/GeoJsonOptions;)V in class Lcom/mapbox/mapboxsdk/style/sources/GeoJsonSource; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.sources.GeoJsonSource' appears in /data/app/Me.MyApp-ALhfKnyL4l3OfYHrn1IyAQ==/base.apk)
                                                                     at com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.utils.MapUtils.updateMapSourceFromFeatureCollection(MapUtils.java:43)
                                                                     at com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.route.NavigationMapRoute.drawRoutes(NavigationMapRoute.java:307)
                                                                     at com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.route.NavigationMapRoute.addRoutes(NavigationMapRoute.java:244)
                                                                     at com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.route.NavigationMapRoute.addRoute(NavigationMapRoute.java:226)
                                                                     at Me.MyApp.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:231)
                                                                     at com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.MapboxDirections$1.onResponse(MapboxDirections.java:167)
                                                                     at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: plz show your gradle file.

Comment: Added build.gradle @sontruongit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:** Remove two line of codes from gradle file then sync, clean and build again.

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.5.1'
implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.0.1@aar') {
        transitive=true
    }
```

Comment: Still has the same error output. I added the full output for more clarity. Just another question, would this code, given I can view the map, have a MapboxMap variable named mapboxMap, would this be all I need to hardcode draw a route from originPosition to destinationPosition? Thanks

Comment: Thanks @sontruongit, fixed issue, route is displayed. Turns out I also removed some calls to locationengine and it fixed the crashes. I have some black dots on my map when I click and create a route however, and when I zoom in it disappears. Seems like the black dots are icons denoting highways and other things, and their colors get inverted, making it black. Is this just an issue with the emulator and I can ignore? (My android studio version is very old)